# Issues with geom_bar with geom_line. Bars disappeared in the combined plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a barplot and a line plot and want to combine them. 
I found the correct tweaking code for the dual-axes issue.
But my bars in my barplots disappeared. Can you help me out.

```
#code to stack overflow
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)

temp = data.frame(Product=as.factor(c("A","B","C")),
                  N = c(17100,17533,6756),
                  n = c(5,13,11),
                  rate = c(0.0003,0.0007,0.0016),
                  labels = c(".03%",".07%",".16%"))

p1 = ggplot(data = temp, aes(x=Product,y=N))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="#F8766D")+geom_text(aes(label=n,col="red",vjust=-0.5))+
  theme(legend.position="none",axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))

p2 = ggplot(data = temp,aes(x=Product,y=rate))+
  geom_line(aes(group=1))+geom_text(aes(label=labels,fill="black",vjust=0))+
  theme(legend.position="none",axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0))+
  xlab("Product")
#code to stack overflow

#new code learned from SO

# extract gtable
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)

# overlap the panel of 2nd plot on that of 1st plot
pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r))
g <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "panel")]], pp$t, 
                     pp$l, pp$b, pp$l)

# axis tweaks
ia <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis-l")
ga <- g2$grobs[[ia]]
ax <- ga$children[[2]]
ax$widths <- rev(ax$widths)
ax$grobs <- rev(ax$grobs)
ax$grobs[[1]]$x <- ax$grobs[[1]]$x - unit(1, "npc") + unit(0.15, "cm")
g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g2$widths[g2$layout[ia, ]$l], length(g$widths) - 1)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, ax, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)

# draw it
grid.draw(g)
```

[image: barplot]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The p2 plot covers the p1 plot; thus nothing of p1 shows through. Set the colour of the p2 panel.background to NA (and more than likely you will want to set the panel.grid in p2 to element_blank).  That is, add `theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA), panel.grid = element_blank())` to p2.

Comment: Thanks greatly! That saved my day.

Comment: Hi Sandy, how can I completely get rid of everything on the right side (including the labels and ticks), I need to save space to align 10 charts side by side.   Specifying  axis.text.y = element_blank()) for p2 removes labels but I also want to remove the ticks. Thank you.

Comment: `theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(), axis.ticks =  element_blank(), axis.ticks.margin = unit(0, "lines"), axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "cm"))` removes marginal material. You need `library(grid)` to access units.